# Scala spring boot autowiring does not work

Tags: java, scala, spring-boot, autowired

I am trying to use spring boot along with scala.
Although I have been able to bootstrap it using `CommandLineRunner` , but I am unable to autowire other scala beans. Following is the code :-

```
import com.service.UtilService
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.{CommandLineRunner, SpringApplication}


@SpringBootApplication
class ScalaMain (@Autowired util:UtilService) extends CommandLineRunner{

  override def run(args: String*): Unit = {
    println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
    util.sayHello
  }
}
object ScalaMain {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    SpringApplication.run(classOf[ScalaMain]);
  }
}
```

This is the service class, that will be autowired into the above mentioned class

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@Service
class UtilService {

  def sayHello = println("A hello from utilService")
}
```

When i run the gradle task "gradle clean bootRun", I get the following error

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.bhargo.bootstrap.ScalaMain required a bean of type 'com.bhargo.service.UtilService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.bhargo.service.UtilService' in your configuration.
```

What is wrong here ?? Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Amar

Answer (score 1):

I got the issue, was doing this when using java, but kinda forgot while using scala. The issue was that the class used for bootstraping was not in the parent package of the other classes whose beans I was creating using the `@Service` annotation. I changed the package structure and now it works like a charm!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing package declarations from your files.  Makes sure you have

```
package com.bhargo.bootstrap
```

at the top of your service class file

Comment: I have that at the top,  missed it in the code while pasting here.